# How to include a detailed response to a detailed answer

Tags: discussion

I have a question ([Cross join on a numbers table to get line vertices, is there a better way?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154995/cross-join-on-a-numbers-table-to-get-line-vertices-is-there-a-better-way)) where I received a very thorough/detailed [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156109/100880). The answer wasn't so much an *answer* as it was a *series of questions*.

I found the answer to be immensely helpful, and thought it was only fair to post my results (found in Update #3).

However, it has occurred to me that 'posting my results' might not fit the Stack Exchange format (it is also quite long). I've considered deleting Update #3 from my question, but I just *know* it's going to be useful to the odd SE member down the line (especially [Geographic Information Systems SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) members who stumble onto this page). It would seem a shame to just erase it.

Is there a better way for me to communicate a detailed response to a detailed answer? Or should I not include a response at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have not looked at the specifics here, just commenting in general.*

**You shouldn't add an answer to the question** (unless it's an "answer" you can't use - sometimes that can be helpful to prevent answerers from wasting time on that solution). People look to the question for the problem, and the answers for the solutions.

**An answer being helpful** doesn't necessarily mean it **has to be** the accepted answer. Many answers can be helpful, but there can still only be a single accepted solution.

Your options in this case (again, from your description, not from going and inspecting):

1. Add an answer indicating the solution you took.
2. Edit their answer to include the route you ended up taking.

If your dilemma is about *rewarding* the person who posted the helpful series-of-questions-as-an-answer with more than a single up-vote, you can either (a) accept their answer and not your own, or (b) accept your own answer but give them a reward via a bounty.

If your dilemma is about having an answer that is way too long, perhaps all of the details shouldn't be included here. For example, you could say "I solved this using this approach, and I wrote up more details about it [link to a blog post]." Answers here don't have to be exhaustive and completely self-contained as instruction manuals on their own, but they should have enough information to be useful even if any destination pages linked to become stale.